# What is wrong with this map query? I am getting the below error

Tags: php, sql

Model:

```
function mapdisplay($lat1,$lng1,$cid2)
{
   $this->db->select("cname,frmid,frno,(6371 * acos( cos( radians('$lat1') ) * cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians(longi) - radians('$lng1') ) + sin( radians('$lat1') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) )AS distance)");
   $this->db->from("tablefir");
   $this->db->where("frmid NOT IN ($cid2)");
   $this->db->having("distance <= 1");
   $this->db->order_by("distance LIMIT 20");
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') FROM (`tablefir`) WHERE `frmid` NOT IN (5,10) HAVING
>   `distance` <= 1 ORDER BY ' at line 1

```
SELECT `crimehead`
    ,`frmid`
    ,`firno`
    ,(6371 * acos(cos(radians('15.859151')) * cos(radians(lat)) 
           * cos(radians(longi) - radians('74.513124')) + sin(radians('15.859151')) 
           * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance )
FROM (`tablefir`)
WHERE `frmid` NOT IN (
        5
        ,10
        )
HAVING `distance` <= 1
ORDER BY `distance` LIMIT 20
```

Comment: why tag javascript and ajax? any particular reason?

Comment: Voting to close as _his question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You given one extra closing braces, change your query with this

```
SELECT crimehead
    ,frmid
    ,firno
    ,(6371 * acos(cos(radians('15.859151')) * cos(radians(lat)) 
           * cos(radians(longi) - radians('74.513124')) + sin(radians('15.859151')) 
           * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance
FROM (tablefir)
WHERE frmid NOT IN (
        5
        ,10
        )
HAVING distance <= 1
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20;
```